# Recharge Battery with Multiple Chargers

Tags: battery-charging

I have (2) 12v 60amp hour batteries connected in parallel used as backup power for my electronics.

I have (2) chargers, 12V 6amp. 
Is it safe to use both chargers at the same time while the batteries are interconnected?

If i decide to expand my parallel connections to 4 or 5 batteries can I use 4 or 5 chargers on each battery while the batteries are all connected?

Comment: What battery chemistry do you have? Li-ion? Lead/acid? NiMH?

Comment: they are: http://www.vmaxtanks.com/servlet/Detail?no=52

Comment: Those are AGM (Absorbed Glass Mat), a type of lead-acid battery

Comment: why the downvote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Connecting battery chargers in parallel is not a good idea. They can interact with each other, e.g. if they momentarily switch off the charge current in order to monitor the battery voltage. This can lead to a charger thinking the battery is fully charged, when it is not, and stopping the charge process.

If your chargers are very crude, with no sensing electronics, then it might work. You'd have to use chargers that were little more than a transformer and a rectifier, though.

Much better to get a bigger charger.

Comment: thank you,  the recommended charger for this battery was `14.5v 7a`.  If i went with a bigger charger should i look for `14.5v 14a`?

Comment: @tq Yes, if you have two batteries in parallel, then you'll need double the current to charge them in the same time. Same voltage, of course.